# Why don't people impute missing exposure data in database studies?

Tags: missing-data, multiple-imputation

Investigators doing studies in large databases (e.g., EMR) in which there is often a lot of missing data usually (in my experience) want to exclude all subjects missing the exposure or outcome of interest, and then use a principled missing data method like multiple imputation to handle missing data on other covariates.

I don't understand this practice, as it seems to result in a cohort that is not defined based on clear scientific grounds as well as in biased and inefficient point estimates [e.g., 1-2].

**My question is: Why is it standard practice to treat missing exposure data in a less principled manner than we treat missing covariate data?**

#### References

[1] Demissie, S., LaValley, M. P., Horton, N. J., Glynn, R. J., & Cupples, L. A. (2003). Bias due to missing exposure data using complete‐case analysis in the proportional hazards regression model. Statistics in Medicine, 22(4), 545-557.

[2] Moons, Karel GM, et al. "Using the outcome for imputation of missing predictor values was preferred." Journal of Clinical Epidemiology 59.10 (2006): 1092-1101.

Comment: It is not my area of expertise, but I guess it would be worthwhile if you somehow backed up the statement that this is a common practice.

Comment: I think there was for a time the feeling that imputing the outcome was inappropriate but I do not think that is common these days.

Comment: @Tim, I can only refer to my personal experiences collaborating primarily with medical investigators. I'd say I've seen this practice firsthand about 5 times in the past few year.

Answer (score 3):

This quote suggests that it may be due to fears of "circularity" and a failure to appreciate the stochastic elements of multiple imputation.

> At first glance, using an outcome variable to impute an incomplete independent variable may seem incorrect and somewhat circular. However, the addition of a random residual term to each imputed value eliminates any bias that might result from doing so (Little & Rubin, 2002). In fact, multiple imputation programs make no distinction between independent and dependent variables and only require you to specify a set of input variables.
>
> -- Craig Enders, *Applied Missing Data Analysis* (p. 202)

Comment: Interesting. That seems like a plausible explanation.